# Fetch API using React Hooks with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I was able to load on initial state, but when I try to submit a new value, I get undefined in my form:

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ list: [] });
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('Miami');
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('Miami');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}&q=${search},us`
      );
      setData(result.data);
      console.log(search);
    };
    console.log(fetchData());

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View>
        <Text>
          To get started, enter a location
        </Text>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            value={query}
            onChangeText={e => setQuery(e)}
          />
          <Button
            type='button'
            title='Fetch!'
            onPress={e => console.log(setSearch(query))}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          {isLoading ? (
            <Text>Fetching weather...</Text>
          ) : (
            data.list.map(item => <Text key={item.dt}>{item.main.temp}</Text>)
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

First load, I get the data, then I try changing the city, and I'm just getting undefined. Why is this?

I thought that if I do setSearch in onPress button, it should get the value from the input field, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your setup is right.

I dont think this line actually returns anything since you are just updating your state:

```
console.log(setSearch(query)) //this would give undefined
```

Keep your Button as:

```
      <Button
        type='button'
        title='Fetch!'
        onPress={e => (setSearch(query))}
      />
```

The state-change is definitely happening in the background. You just need to update your `useEffect()` to listen for a change in `search` state. So now `useEffect()` will execute whenever there is a new city value.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}&q=${search},us`
      );
      setData(result.data);
      console.log(search);
    };
    console.log(fetchData());

    fetchData();
  }, [search]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The hook does not list search as dependency so it does not run every time the search term changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}&q=${search},us`
      );
      setData(result.data);
      console.log(search);
    };
    console.log(fetchData());

    fetchData();
  }, [ search ]);
```